# Visual Studio Code cancelling chord sequence and use trigger as command

Tags: visual-studio-code

Consider following VS Code Keybindings configuration:

```
        {
            "key": "ctrl+j j",
            "command": "some-command-one"
        },
        {
            "key": "ctrl+j",
            "command": "some-command-two"
        },
```

It translates to two bindings configuration:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> and then <kbd>j</kbd> triggers `some-command-two` (chord-based command binding)
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> triggers `some-command-two`

Unfortunately, point 2) does not working. VS Code awaits for chord and if no character is received after some time delay, nothings happens, action is cancelled. This behavior makes sense in default cases, but I'm wondering can it be pushed forward. I know that the easiest way of working this around would be via defining two chord-waiting commands, like:

```
            "key": "ctrl+j j",
            "command": "some-command-one"
        },
        {
            "key": "ctrl+j h",
            "command": "some-command-two"
        },
```

So my question would be, is there a way to tell VS Code, that key combination that is defined as chord waiting trigger shall be cancelled and base-defined keybinding shall be executed instead?

Comment: if a key+modifiers is used as a prefix you can't use it as a single key bind. VSC does not know when to choose or how long to wait, and if you want `ctrl+j j` but wait a bit to long before pressing second `j` you get command-two and a `j`, this will confuse a lot of users and unneeded complexity in VSC with maybe a lot of settings to allow it conditionally

Comment: This totally makes sense after thinking for a while. @rioV8 are you willing to convert this comment into response, So I can formally accept this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a key+modifiers is used as a prefix you can't use it as a single key bind.

VSC does not know when to choose or how long to wait, and if you want `ctrl+j j` but wait a bit to long before pressing second `j` you get `command-two` and a `j`, this will confuse a lot of users and unneeded complexity in VSC with maybe a lot of settings to allow it conditionally